# Toggle checkboxe show/hide using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, vb.net

I have the below table populated with data using AJAX/JSON
When I click on a particular row, it populates some textboxes with values from the table row which works fine,based on a value in the row, I will either hide or show some checkboxes but I cant get that part to work.
Below is my code,dont know what am doing wrong.
Thanks for your help in advance

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        "responsive"; true,
        "serverSide"; true,
        "info"; true,
        "stateSave"; true,
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "json",
         url:"CustomerService.asmx/GetCustomer",
         success: function (data) {
             var datatableVariable = $('#dtCustomers').DataTable({

                 data: data,
                 columns: [
                     { 'data': 'iD' },
                     { 'data': 'AccountNumber' },
                     { 'data': 'Name' },
                      { 'data': 'FirstName' },
                       { 'data': 'LastName' },
                        { 'data': 'Balance' },
                         { 'data': 'TypeOfAccount' }
                 ],
                 columnDefs: [
             { "visible": false, "targets": 0 },
              { "visible": false, "targets": 3 },
               { "visible": false, "targets": 4 },
               { "visible": false, "targets": 6 }
                 ]
             });
             datatableVariable.columns().every(function () {
                 var column = this;
                 $(this.footer()).find('input').on('keyup change', function () {
                     column.search(this.value).draw();
                 });
             });
             $('.showHide').on('click', function () {
                 var tableColumn = datatableVariable.column($(this).attr('data-columnindex'));
                 tableColumn.visible(!tableColumn.visible());
             });


             $('#dtCustomers').on('click', 'tr', function () {

                 var data = datatableVariable.row(this).data();
                 $(document.getElementById('<%= customerids.ClientID %>')).val(data.iD);
                 $(document.getElementById('<%= lblFnames.ClientID %>')).val(data.FirstName);
                 $(document.getElementById('<%= lblLnames.ClientID %>')).val(data.LastName);
                 $(document.getElementById('<%= lblacc.ClientID %>')).val(data.AccountNumber);
                 $(document.getElementById('<%= lblBals.ClientID %>')).val(data.Balance);
                 $(document.getElementById('<%= acctypes.ClientID %>')).val(data.TypeOfAccount);
                 //debugger;
                 switch (data.TypeOfAccount) {
                     case 0:
                         $(document.getElementById('<%= chkNCs.ClientID %>')).hide
                         $(document.getElementById('<%= chkODs.ClientID %>')).hide
                         $(document.getElementById('<%= chkRODs.ClientID %>')).hide
                         break;
                     case 4:
                         $(document.getElementById('<%= chkNCs.ClientID %>')).visible
                         $(document.getElementById('<%= chkODs.ClientID %>')).visible
                         $(document.getElementById('<%= chkRODs.ClientID %>')).visible
                         break;

                     default:

                 }
             });
         }
     });
    });

</script>
<div class="">
   <ul style="list-style-type:none;float:left;display: inline;margin:0;padding:0;">
      <li class="list"><asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="chkRODs" name="chkRODs"  Text="Repayment of OD" visible="false"/></li>
      <li class="list"><asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="chkODs" name="chkODs"  Text="Interest on Repayment" visible="false" /></li>
     <li class="list"><asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="chkNCs" name="chkNCs"  Text="Non-Cash Transaction" visible="false" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just to add, the checkboxes are asp checkboxes

Comment: `.hide()` not `.hide` - without the () the method will not actually execute. And use `.show()` as the opposite, not `.visible` - that's just a property of a HTML object (so you'd have to set it), but it doesn't exist on jQuery objects, which you're trying to use it against.

Comment: also you can just do `$('#<%= chkNCs.ClientID %>')` instead of `$(document.getElementById('<%= chkNCs.ClientID %>'))` - jQuery can accept a CSS selector string instead of the actual element object. Saves a bit of typing and probably makes a tiny performance improvement as well

Comment: Thanks, could you please suggest a better option if it doesnt exist on jQuery objects?

Comment: I just did - `.show()`. Read the comment again :-)

Comment: Thanks, I did but still not showing,I used CHrome DevTools and it executed without any errors but still didnt show

Comment: can you show the related HTML/ASPX markup?

Comment: On Pageload the checkboxes are not visible :), sorry I didnt add that

Comment: Hm, I think if you set the "Visible=false" option on the ASPX control, that means that the markup for the checkboxes is never rendered to the page - you could verify this by using View Source on the finished page and searching for them. You'd have to set them invisible using CSS instead (maybe a class that's applied to them, with `display:none` set). otherwise the Javascript cannot have any influence on them, because they don't exist.

Comment: '<ul style="list-style-type:none;float:left;display: inline;margin:0;padding:0;">
      <li class="list"><asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="chkRODs" name="chkRODs" visible="false" Text="Repayment of OD" /></li>
                                                    <li class="list"><asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="chkODs" name="chkODs" visible="false" Text="Interest on Repayment" /></li></ul>'

Comment: sorry am new to this site so couldnt get the 'code' to rendered very well

Comment: Code in comments is generally unreadable. Please edit the question itself, then it's also visible for future readers.

Comment: Replace`Visible="false"` with `style="display:none;"` on the checkbox controls and then try the show()/hide() methods again.

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: is it definitely going to the right part of the switch statement?

Comment: I've also just noticed that all this is within the context of your "success" function. That means, every time the ajax function runs, you create another copy of all the event handlers - meaning if you run the ajax 3 times, there will be 3 "click" event handlers for every table row. That could be confusing things. You either need to remove the previous handlers using "off" or declare the handlers outside the ajax method.

Comment: I think its working,but I should rather hide the whole  html item list rather than  only the  asp checkbox.Please how can I do that
Thanks for the earlier correction, I have declared the handles outside the AJAX method

Comment: give your enclosing `<div>` an ID, and then use show() and hide() on that instead. It will hide everything inside it. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/5hyvwLqg/ (I couldn't use aspx checkboxes obviously, but you get the idea, it doesn't matter for the example).

Comment: hahaha... thax , its working, am truly grateful for the ideas
Please how can I mark it as answered

Comment: I will make an answer out of it, hang on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few points to note with the code given here:

1) Because you set the "Visible=false" option on the ASPX control, that means that the markup for the checkboxes is never rendered to the page - you could verify this by using View Source on the finished page and searching for them.

2) it should be `.hide()` not `.hide` - without the `()` the method will not actually execute. And you should use `.show()` as the opposite, not `.visible` - that's just a property of a HTML object (so you'd have to set it), but it doesn't exist on jQuery objects, which you're trying to use it against.

3) All this is done within the context of your ajax "success" function. That means, every time the ajax function runs, you create another copy of all the event handlers - meaning if you run the ajax 3 times, there will be 3 "click" event handlers for every table row. That could be confusing things. You either need to remove the previous handlers using "off" or declare the handlers outside the ajax method.

Then finally, the simplest and least verbose way to toggle all your checkboxes is to actually toggle the enclosing div - that will hide everything within it:

**HTML**

```
<div id="options" style="display:none;">
   <ul style="list-style-type:none;float:left;display: inline;margin:0;padding:0;">
      <li class="list"><asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="chkRODs" name="chkRODs"  Text="Repayment of OD" /></li>
      <li class="list"><asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="chkODs" name="chkODs"  Text="Interest on Repayment" /></li>
     <li class="list"><asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="chkNCs" name="chkNCs"  Text="Non-Cash Transaction" /></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$('#dtCustomers').on('click', 'tr', function () {
  var data = datatableVariable.row(this).data();
  //etc...until
  switch (data.TypeOfAccount) {
    case 0:
      $("#options").hide();
      break;
    case 4:
      $("#options").show();
      break;
    default:
  }
});
```

See a simplified but working example demonstrating the principle here: https://jsfiddle.net/5hyvwLqg/

Comment: Thanks, Dont know if I should open another thread as this is answered,regarding your suggestion to declare the handler outside the ajax method, its because am using the data returned from the AJAX call thats why its done within the context of the "success" function, but your suggestion is great, how do i achieve that

Comment: declare `var datatableVariable = null;` before your document.ready function, so it has global scope. Then inside the ajax, write `datatableVariable = $('#dtCustomers').DataTable({` instead of `var datatableVariable = $('#dtCustomers').DataTable({` (i.e. without the `var` which would redeclare it). Then you should be able to access the latest version of `dataTableVariable` from within your event handlers.

Comment: P.S. Please don't forget to "accept" the answer :-)